Does the MLE exist with only one sample? For example: $X_1 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.
Is it true that $\hat{u} = x_1$ and $\hat{\sigma} = 0$? What happens if $X_1 \sim U(0, \theta)$, with just one sample?

One would first need to define MLE

You need to spend some quality time with your post.
